# The administrator has banned my IP address. What is problem

Tags: ip

I am not a very experienced Ubuntu user, so I have to look up some information on the internet. Most of the links lead to http://ubuntuforums.org. But each time I try to open a page on this site, it says "Sorry. The administrator has banned your IP address. To contact the administrator click here". That seems strange, because it is the first time I have ever been on ubuntuforums.org.

The worst thing is: when I click on the word "here" to contact the administrator, it says "The administrator may have required you to register before you can view this page." I tried logging in with SSO as it says, but when I open the login page, the message about my ban appears again.

I tried to contact the ForumCouncil from their page, but it gives me the same error => I can't open it

Is there any way to find out the reason why my IP was banned? Thank you.

Comment: does your internet connection have a static or dynamic IP?

Comment: Are you in Russia or china? perhaps the admin has black listed your subnet. I mean, when i see malicious attacks come in I block n.n.n.0/24

Comment: No, I am a Bangladeshi.

Comment: This is not actually a duplicate in a sense that this does not directly address the problem of contacting the administrator of Ubuntuforums rather its a IP address ban issue. This can happen on other sites too, all of those sites will show that "The administrator has blocked the site for your IP" or something similar. When you are using Mobile broadband i.e. mobile operator provided internet, they will use NAT to broadcast thousands of private IP addresses as merely a single public IP.

Comment: So if spamming or DoS attempted by any of the private IPs under that public IP, the administrator will ban the public IP as a protective measure. So all the innocent users under that public IP will face this denial too.